# Build a table with total unique values for each group in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am using google spreadsheets.

Imagine there are some families of insects with the following names in column A, and their genera in column B and C imaginary names for species (they are unique FOR each genus).

What I need is to have for EACH FAMILY (column A) the UNIQUE number of genus. I'll give the desired result after this table 1.

NOTE: Culicidae has 31 rows

Table 1- Original table

```
   A           B               C 
    ---------------------------------
1   Culicidae   Aedes           X
2   Culicidae   Aedes           Y
    Culicidae   Aedes           Z
    Culicidae   Aedes           W
    Culicidae   Aedes           E  
    Culicidae   Anopheles       X
    Culicidae   Anopheles       Y
    Culicidae   Anopheles       Z
    Culicidae   Anopheles       C
    Culicidae   Anopheles       V
    Culicidae   Anopheles       I
    Culicidae   Anopheles       P
    Culicidae   Anopheles       L
    Culicidae   Anopheles       U
    Culicidae   Coquillettidia  A
    Culicidae   Culex           X
    Culicidae   Culex           Y 
    Culicidae   Culex           Z
    Culicidae   Culex           V
    Culicidae   Culex           B
    Culicidae   Culex           N
    Culicidae   Culex           M
    Culicidae   Culex           O
    Culicidae   Culex           P
    Culicidae   Culiseta        A 
    Culicidae   Culiseta        B
    Culicidae   Culiseta        C
    Culicidae   Culiseta        T
    Culicidae   Culiseta        Y
    Culicidae   Orthopodomyia   W 
    Culicidae   Uranotaenia     A
32  Tephritidae Tephritis       X
```

Table 2.  Desired result

```
Family            Total Number of Unique Genera
--------------------------------------------------
Culicidae                 7
Tephritidae               1
```

Culicidae has 7 unique values for column B, hence the final desired result in another new table (table 2 in another different sheet) should be 7 for this case.

So we need first to find the range for Culicidae (it is dynamic - today the values for Culicidae can range from A1 to A31, and tomorrow from A100 to A130 or whatever, and can increase or decrease with the time, ie, today has 31 rows, tomorrow can have 90 rows or 29 rows...). Ideally, it should group each family automatically in column A for the TABLE 2.

Then for Culicidae it should find out how many unique genera are in column B, THEY ARE 7 unique values. And that's it. I hope this clears out.

I know that to find the unique values should be something like (but this range is static.. and not dynamic as desired...):

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/countif($B$1:$B$31,$B$1:$B$31))`

The main difficulty is to achieve the right range ($B$1:$B$31 or where it is the data for Culicidae) IN only one formula (that can be dynamic, and to group each family as shown in Table 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use formula:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(A1:B, 99^99, 2, 2, 1), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! I got the sql part. I am not aware about the meaning on 2,2,1 part. the rest is understandable! What if we want to extend to count all C rows for each family (column A)? 
i tried with the next modified snippet - the error must be in the 3,3,1?  
`=QUERY(SORTN(A1:C, 99^99, 3, 3, 1), 
"select Col1,count(Col1), count(Col0)
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col0
group by Col1
label count(Col1)''")`

Comment: `99^99` = all possible rows. `2` = 2nd mode of sortn resulting in collapsing of same values located in following column. `2` = column that needs to be collapsed. `1` = ascending mode

Comment: thanks. nevertheless I still need to know the total of column C for each family... Culicidae wou.ld give 31, and Tephritidae only one result. with this it is not working: 

`=QUERY(SORTN(A1:C, 99^99, 2, 1, 2, 1),  "select Col1,count(Col1), count(Col0) where Col1 is not null  group by Col0 group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")` the column C is never null.

Comment: You hadn't asked for a row count by family in your first question.  That is easily added with this query:  ```=QUERY(A:A,"select A, count(A) where A <> '' group by A label count(A) ''  ")```.    The two queries could be combined into a single formula, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be achieved in a formula, utilizing the Pivot Table function will result in the second table that you are looking for, as well as being dynamic.

In Google sheets, select your data range (*Table 1*) -> Click on the `Data` -> Select `Pivot Table`. From there confirm that the data range is correct and that **New sheet** is selected. Click create and you should be moved to the new sheet with the Pivot table editor pane open.

To get the desired output as *Table 2* add `Family` to **Rows** and `Genera` to **Values**. By default Genera will be summarized by **COUNTA**; in order to get the UNIQUE  Count all you need to do is change **COUNTA** to **COUNTUNIQUE**.

This Table will update automatically to any changes made within the original range, however make sure that if you add/remove any new rows that you update the **Data Range** within the Pivot table editor.